# python multiprocessing write data to the same list

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing

I want to write data to the same list via python multiprocessing, I do interprocess data sharing via mp.manager.list. The code is shown below, this is just a demo, I want to add the same numbers to the same list. However, counter can be increased, but grp remains the same. Where is the problem?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import random
import time

import numpy as np

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.raw = [random.randint(1, 4) for _ in range(100)]
        self.manager = mp.Manager()
        self.grp = self.manager.list([[1], [2], [3], [4]])
        self.use_cpu_num = 2
        self.counter = self.manager.Value('i', 0)

    def run(self):
        subsets = np.array_split(self.raw, self.use_cpu_num)
        subsets = [each.tolist() for each in subsets]
        process = []
        for i in range(self.use_cpu_num):
            process.append(mp.Process(target=self.process, args=(subsets[i], )))
        for each in process:
            each.start()
        for each in process:
            each.join()
            each.close()
        print(self.grp)

    def process(self, subset):
        for each in subset:
            for i in range(len(self.grp)):
                each_grp = self.grp[i]
                if each in each_grp:
                    self.counter.set(self.counter.value + 1)
                    self.grp[i].append(each)
                    print(self.counter.value)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    a.run()
```

I tried using mp.Lock(), but that doesn't share data between different processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it this way, `self.grp` is a managed object, any change on it using `self.grp.append` or `self.grp[i] = x` will be transferred to the manager process.

The objects inside `self.grp` are not managed, any change to them will **not** be transferred to the manager, you only get a **copy** of them when you use `self.grp[i]`.

In order to allow modifications to the lists inside `self.grp` to propagate, those lists must themselves be `manager.list` object, and nesting managed objects is not supported for versions of python below 3.6

```py
self.grp = self.manager.list([self.manager.list(x) for x in ([1], [2], [3], [4])])
```

If you are only storing numbers you can pass `multiprocessing.Array` which can be wrapped as a numpy ndarray for convenience, but you cannot append to it, and must know the size beforehand.

Edit: on windows you will get an error when trying to pickle the `self.manager` object, so i modified it out of the class in the example below.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import random
import time

import numpy as np
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.raw = [random.randint(1, 4) for _ in range(100)]
        self.grp = manager.list([manager.list(x) for x in ([1], [2], [3], [4])])
        self.use_cpu_num = 2
        self.counter = manager.Value('i', 0)

    def run(self):
        subsets = np.array_split(self.raw, self.use_cpu_num)
        subsets = [each.tolist() for each in subsets]
        process = []
        for i in range(self.use_cpu_num):
            process.append(mp.Process(target=self.process, args=(subsets[i], )))
        for each in process:
            each.start()
        for each in process:
            each.join()
            each.close()
        print([list(x) for x in self.grp])

    def process(self, subset):
        for each in subset:
            for i in range(len(self.grp)):
                each_grp = self.grp[i]
                if each in each_grp:
                    self.counter.set(self.counter.value + 1)
                    self.grp[i].append(each)
                    print(self.counter.value)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = mp.Manager()
    a = A()
    a.run()
```

Comment: So it was, thank you very much! problem is solved!!!